# Use the default-input-method when doing an incremental search in EVIL?

Tags: emacs, customization, evil-mode

Before loading EVIL for vim emulation in emacs, I have the following in my `.emacs` file:

```
(activate-input-method "english-dvorak")
(setq default-input-method "english-dvorak")
```

However, when I type `/` to start an incremental search with EVIL, the default input method is not used. Why is this? How can I make it so EVIL uses default-input-method whenever I am typing letters on screen?

I was able to hack in proper support for the `f` and `t` commands by mapping the qwerty characters to dvorak before the rest of the those function's code executed, but I still haven't been able to get my searches with `/` to use dvorak.

Comment: C-h f toggle-input-method should help.

Comment: This works fine for me. Are you using vanilla search? Does it work if you start emacs with `-Q`?

Comment: @Thomas I apologize, my problem was actually more complex that I thought, and I have updated the question to reflect this. The solution above actually works fine in vanilla emacs, but it does NOT work in EVIL.

Answer (score 2):

I've tested the following configuration on my PC and it seem to make Dvorak to be on everywhere in Emacs:

```lisp
;; Main setup for  all the buffers
(defadvice switch-to-buffer (after activate-input-method activate)
  (activate-input-method "english-dvorak"))

;; Sets up Dvorak for the minibuffer
(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook (lambda () (set-input-method "english-dvorak")))

;; Sets up Dvorak for *scratch* buffer (used Qwerty on my PC otherwise)
(save-excursion
  (set-buffer (get-buffer "*scratch*"))
  (set-input-method "english-dvorak"))
```

Comment: I apologize, my problem was actually more complex that I thought, and I have updated the question to reflect this. I followed the procedure I originally outlined and the problem disappeared, although it looks like your advice would also do the trick. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that **Evil**'s incremental searches are performed in normal-state, which, to my knowledge, cannot be used with an input method. This is a quick hack that switches to insert-state just before performing a search to allow the use of input methods. Since it switches to back normal-state immediately after the search is finished, the only quirk is a different cursor in the buffer while you are performing the search.

```
 (evil-define-motion evil-search-forward ()
  (format "Search forward for user-entered text.
Searches for regular expression if `evil-regexp-search' is t.%s"
          (if (and (fboundp 'isearch-forward)
                   (documentation 'isearch-forward))
              (format "\n\nBelow is the documentation string \
for `isearch-forward',\nwhich lists available keys:\n\n%s"
                      (documentation 'isearch-forward)) ""))
  :jump t
  :type exclusive
  :repeat evil-repeat-search
    (progn                 ;MADE CHANGES HERE
      (evil-insert-state)
      (evil-search-incrementally t evil-regexp-search)
      (evil-normal-state)
    ))

(evil-define-motion evil-search-backward ()
  (format "Search forward for user-entered text.
Searches for regular expression if `evil-regexp-search' is t.%s"
          (if (and (fboundp 'isearch-forward)
                   (documentation 'isearch-forward))
              (format "\n\nBelow is the documentation string \
for `isearch-forward',\nwhich lists available keys:\n\n%s"
                      (documentation 'isearch-forward)) ""))
  :jump t
  :type exclusive
  :repeat evil-repeat-search
    (progn                 ;MADE CHANGES HERE
      (evil-insert-state)
      (evil-search-incrementally nil evil-regexp-search)
      (evil-normal-state)
    ))
```